# How to suppress Jupyter's keybindings during the work with terminals?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, jupyter, jupyterlab

I would like to use terminal sessions in **Jupyter Lab** as the staple tool. But the problem is to use specific keybindings, for instance, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> for deleting command parts or <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> for `tmux` management. Unfortunately, I could not find any appropriate solution. Of course, I can set `null` for all built-in keybindings in the settings `json`, but this is not a solution.